Why does Ubuntu 24.04 not stay in suspend?
When I select suspend from the menu it goes to suspend but bounces right out again.
The only thing I see in journalctl is a message from NetworkManager that the interface switched from unmanaged -> unavailable.
Yes, my network is configured and works fine.
I searched for solutions but the only similar thing I could find was somebody having this problem who solved it by upgrading their kernel.
According to free I have 8 GB of swap which is less than my 64 GB of memory. However, the system seems to go into suspend for a second but then wakes up again. So that's probably not the issue.
Here is some journalctl output from the event:
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd-logind[1447]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
May 27 10:25:03 tmp ModemManager[1608]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
May 27 10:25:03 tmp NetworkManager[1482]: <info>  [1716798303.9671] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
May 27 10:25:03 tmp NetworkManager[1482]: <info>  [1716798303.9672] device (enp16s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: Starting fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: Finished grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB.
May 27 10:25:03 tmp systemd[1]: Starting grub-initrd-fallback.service - GRUB failed boot detection...
May 27 10:25:03 tmp kernel: RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY r8169-0-1000:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-1000:00, irq=MAC)
May 27 10:25:04 tmp systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 27 10:25:04 tmp systemd[1]: Finished grub-initrd-fallback.service - GRUB failed boot detection.
May 27 10:25:04 tmp dbus-daemon[1421]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
May 27 10:25:04 tmp systemd[1]: Started fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
May 27 10:25:04 tmp gnome-shell[3285]: no authentication service is enabled, using password authentication
May 27 10:25:04 tmp gnome-shell[3285]: no authentication service is enabled, using password authentication
May 27 10:25:04 tmp rtkit-daemon[2250]: Recovering from system lockup, not allowing further RT threads.
May 27 10:25:04 tmp gnome-shell[3285]: Failed to make thread 'KMS thread' normally scheduled: Operation not permitted
May 27 10:25:04 tmp kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device setup in 159699 usecs
May 27 10:25:04 tmp kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
May 27 10:25:04 tmp kernel: r8169 0000:10:00.0 enp16s0: Link is Down
May 27 10:25:04 tmp rtkit-daemon[2250]: Recovering from system lockup, not allowing further RT threads.
May 27 10:25:04 tmp gnome-shell[3285]: Failed to make thread 'KMS thread' normally scheduled: Operation not permitted
May 27 10:25:04 tmp NetworkManager[1482]: <info>  [1716798304.1648] device (wlp17s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 27 10:25:04 tmp NetworkManager[1482]: <info>  [1716798304.1652] device (p2p-dev-wlp17s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 27 10:25:04 tmp NetworkManager[1482]: <info>  [1716798304.1652] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 27 10:25:04 tmp kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v1.00


How do I fix this?

Not enough info, pls see here https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Can you please clarify which information you're missing?

Have you searched anything regarding your problem? issues that were solved in earlier versions of Ubuntu can also solve your issue. interface switched from unmanaged -> unavailable. what you have there? Hae you configured your network? that is just 2 questions, is there any info on your journalctl? have you at all searcehd for Network unmanaged, or unable suspend here and on the web?

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.

@amar I've added more details!

@Warkwark see post 2 in here https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/suspend-bug-for-ubuntu-24-04lts/7853/2
